# How to name axis in excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

This is how I create chart:

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlChartsq = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChartq = (Excel.ChartObject)xlChartsq.Add(10, 1000, 175, 310);
Excel.Chart chartPageq = myChartq.Chart;
myChartq.Select();
```

And I have succesfully named primary axis this way, I have used [MDSN`s code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.axes.aspx):

```
Excel.Axis axis = myChartq.Chart.Axes(
Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,
Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);

axis.HasTitle = true;
axis.AxisTitle.Text = "AXIS`s NAME";
```

It works as should, but then I tried to use such method to name secondary axis, it failed:

```
Excel.Axis axisq = myChartq.Chart.Axes(
Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,
Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary);

axisq.HasTitle = true; 
axisq.AxisTitle.Text = "another AXIS`s NAME";
```

It compiled without any errors, unfortunately after calling this code I got such error:
unexpected exception "**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**", and something like **HRESULT E_FAIL** error was returned.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

**UPD1:**
Before naming I create some series, but, honestly, I can't figure out how it can be associated with `Secondary` axis.

```
for (int i = 0; i < current_Excel_Position; i++ )
{
 Excel.Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
 series1.XValues = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + Convert.ToString(92 + i), "B" +     Convert.ToString(92 + i)); ;
 series1.Values = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C" + Convert.ToString(92 + i), "D" + Convert.ToString(92 + i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be at least one series on the secondary axis. If all your data is on the primary axis you cannot show / edit the secondary axis.

Do you have any series on the secondary axis? If not that is your problem.

Edit: This is how you can set the value (Y axis in your case) and category (X axis in your case):

```
Excel.Axis axisq = myChartq.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,
               Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
axisq.HasTitle = true;
axisq.AxisTitle.Text = "Value axis NAME";

axisq = myChartq.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,
                Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
axisq.HasTitle = true;
axisq.AxisTitle.Text = "Category axis NAME";
```

Comment: Then, how can I add data to secondary axis?

Comment: In most cases you don't even to add data to secondary axis. Why do you want to set the name of the secondary axis in the first place? Maybe what you want is primary category axis, did you try that one? If you really wanted to add data to secondary axis you would do something like this: Excel.SeriesCollection sc = myChartq.Chart.SeriesCollection();Excel.Series series = sc.NewSeries(); series = sc.NewSeries(); series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary; This adds two new series to the chart. The first one to the primary axis (default) and then one more to the secondary.

Comment: I feel stupid myself, yes your solution works,  but I misunderstand, I just wanted to name x-axis, by naming primary axis I have gave the name to  y-axis. Is it hard?